# How to handle a strongly typed modal in a strongly typed view with different types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog, strongly-typed-view

I'm using modals for logging in and registering a user. Each modal is strongly typed to make use of the ASP.NET built-in account classes (`RegisterModel` and `LoginModel`). However, since the two buttons to call these modals are located on the navbar and the navbar is placed on every page I receive errors because most views are strongly typed and thus cannot handle a partialview (the modal) to be using a different strongly typed model.

How are strongly typed modals handled in a strongly typed environment?

_Layout:

```
<body>
 <div class="navbar">
  @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial") // contains buttons to call login/register modals
 </div>

 <div>
  @Html.Partial("_LoginModal")
  @Html.Partial("_RegisterModal")
 </div>

 <div class="container">
  @Html.RenderBody()
 </div>
</body>
```

/News/Index:

```
@model List<NewsBulletinViewModel>
```

LoginModal:

```
@model NoName.Models.LoginModel
```

On a related note:
Since I have forms inside my modals, how can I refer back to those modals when validation errors occur? Ideally the modal should popup again (or never be closed) with the validation errors shown.

Comment: When you call `_LoginModal` or `_RegisterModal` via `@Html.Partial` why do you need to pass a `Model` to it? what would it contain?

Comment: @haim770: see my comment on Simon's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overload in `@Html.Partial` that takes an object, used for the partial page's Model. If you include the Partial in your layout, in every page, you need a logic to keep that data. For example, if you take `LoginModel` and `RegisterModel`, you could do this:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", ViewBag.LoginModel ?? new LoginModel())
@Html.Partial("_RegisterPartial", ViewBag.RegisterModel ?? new RegisterModel())
```

And leave to the executing controller the role to put a `LoginModel` (or `RegisterModel`). If there isn't any in the `ViewBag`, it will fallback to creating an empty one.

**Edit:** Based on the additional information, I'd do this for the `LoginPartial` (`RegisterPartial` would be the same logic):

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult LoginPartial()
    {
        return PartialView("_LoginPartial", (Session["Login"] as LoginModel) ?? new LoginModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpStatusCodeResult SaveLoginModel(LoginModel model)
    {
        Session["Login"] = model;
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
}
```

And then, in `_LoginPartial`, do as you would, but add a javascript code to send an ajax post request to the `SaveLoginModel` action of your controller when the value change to keep your model in sync (there is plenty of information around on how to do that).

Now, instead of doing:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", ViewBag.LoginModel ?? new LoginModel())
@Html.Partial("_RegisterPartial", ViewBag.RegisterModel ?? new RegisterModel())
```

You would do:

```
@Html.Action("LoginPartial", "AccountController");
@Html.Action("RegisterPartial", "AccountController");
```

Comment: I'm using the models of the respective modal to create input fields and perform validation on it while allowing for easy transporting of the entered values to the `AccountController`. As far as I'm concerned, these modals their models can be empty when you're navigating trough the site, but they're very handy when they have to actually be used. Would you suggest to do it differently?

Comment: If I understand right, you want to keep track of what the user entered even if he moves pages. You can do it, but don't forget that http is stateless and if you want to keep track of that, you need to ping your server regularly to save that data somewhere (presumably in the session dictionary). I'll edit my answer to suggest what you could do, but I advise you against it.

Comment: No need, the answer you've given me already fixes it entirely as far as I can see! I just had to find a way to send an empty model to the partialviews so the compiler would stop being angry its model is different from the main view. I've had to change the syntax a little, but the solution you've provided seems to do the trick.

Comment: I updated my answer to propose you a way to do what you wanted.
Edit: It was still an interesting exercise, so I posted it. ;)